# Navigate away from registration screen

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've a signup form of firestorm that is working perfectly, but I can not move away from the signup screen!!

The below code, do the registration in the firestore in a good way, but the `Navigator.pop` is not working, I want to go back to the `Welcome()` screen after posting the data in firestore:

```dart
  void signUp() async {
    if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      try{
        FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
        user.sendEmailVerification();

        var coll = Firestore.instance.collection('baby');
          coll.document(user.uid).setData({});

          coll.document(user.uid).setData({
            "role": "admin",
            "name": _displayname,
            "mobile": _mobile,
            "status": _status,
            "latestupdate":Timestamp.now(),
            "distance": _distance,
            "location": GeoPoint(_lat, _lon)
          });

        UserUpdateInfo userInfo;
        await user.reload();
        userInfo.displayName=  _displayname;
        user.updateProfile(userInfo);

        Navigator.pop(context);

        print(user);
      }catch(e){
        print(e.message);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does popping do anything?

Comment: @JacobPhillips NO

Comment: Maybe it's the only route on the stack? You could also clear the stack and push the route you want onto it. It seems like more information is needed